# How to delete entities using Criterion efficiently?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, optimization, spring-orm

Currently, I have to create a temporary `Criteria` and get the matching entity list using `Criteria.list()`, and then, pass the list to `HibernateTemplate.deleteAll()`:

```
void delete(Criterion criterion) {
    Criteria c = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Foo.class).getExecutableCriteria(session);
    c.add(criterion);
    getHibernateTtemplate().deleteAll(c.list());
}
```

Is it possible to delete by Criterion but without load the list at the first?

Maybe, I should convert the criterion to HQL like `"delete from Foo where " + criterion.toHQL()`?

*BACKGROUNDS*

I have a search form which later be parsed and converted into a Criteria composition.

The search results are retrieved by using Criteria.list().

Now, a question came into the sight, I want to delete all the search results. Should I parse the search form again but in different manner to convert it into an HQL string? If I can reuse the Criteria, things would be simpler.

As the Criteria is most equivalent to WHERE clause, (isn't it?) I see no reason a Criteria couldn't be used for deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indeed only can do this using HQL. There is no criteria API equivalent.

Comment: Then, I would stick with list-and-delete, which does work but just slow.

Comment: Why the preference for Criteria API over HQL?

Comment: Because I had made the most part of API in my local project using Criteria, to prevent programmers do evil things. It also feels better to convert from one composition (search form) to another composition (Criteria).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use method `execute(HibernateCallback action)` from class **HibernateTemplate**. It could look like this:

```
final Criterion criteria;
HibernateTemplate template;
template.execute(new HibernateCallback() {
    @Override
    public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        List toDelete = session.createCriteria(Student.class).add(criteria).list();
        for (Object o: toDelete){
            session.delete(o);
        }
    }
});
```

IMHO this solution is not very efficient, because you must read all entries before you remove them. What is more you must remove each entry individually, which is very unefficient.